# Android - Manifest / Dagger ignoring my custom Application class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I have an Android app that uses a custom application class, it looks something like this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application  
  android:allowBackup="true"  
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"  
  android:label="@string/app_name"  
  android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"  
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"  
  android:supportsRtl="true"  
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  
  android:name=".MyApplication"  
  tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

MyApplication.kt

```
class MyApplication : Application(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector, HasServiceInjector {  
      @Inject  
      lateinit var serviceInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service>  
      @Inject  
      lateinit var fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>  
      @Inject  
      lateinit var activityDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>  
      @Inject  
      lateinit var remoteConfig: FirebaseRemoteConfig  
      @Inject  
      lateinit var workerFactory: GrowWorkerFactory  

      override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = activityDispatchingAndroidInjector  

      override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> = fragmentInjector  

      override fun serviceInjector(): AndroidInjector<Service> = serviceInjector  

}
```

This is my dagger component class

```
interface MyApplicationComponent {  
  @Component.Builder  
    interface Builder {  
  fun build(): MyApplicationComponent  
  @BindsInstance  
  fun application(application: Application): Builder  
  fun dataSourceModule(module: DataSourceModule): Builder  
  fun serviceModule(module: ManagerModule): Builder  
  }  

  fun inject(app: MyApplication)  
}
```

The build completes fine and the app launches, but, when arriving to the SplashActivity class, the app crashes throwing this:

```
2019-05-07 13:13:32.314 14002-14002/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.app.debug, PID: 14002
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app.debug/com.my.app.debug.SplashActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2123)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7470)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.app.Application does not implement dagger.android.HasActivityInjector
        at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:49)
        at com.my.app.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7436)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7426)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3279)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2123) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7470) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

Seems like the app is ignoring MyApplication class

Comment: Are you using `DaggerApplication?`

Comment: No, Ill try extending from that class

Comment: It didn't worked, the same exception appears